# Forward X11 through SSH and open GUI applications from tty

Tags: linux, x11, startx, xinit

If I'm on the tty cli with no desktop environment set up, how can I start a remote desktop environment through ssh?

For exmaple, if I first launch `startx icewm` and from there do a `ssh -X me@raspi startlxde-pi` it starts the pi desktop environment just fine.

But if I do it directly from the TTY, it gives me weird errors and just generally doesn't work. I've also tried normally ssh-ing into it `ssh -X me@raspi` and then running it `startlxde-pi` and it still doesn't work.

The error I get is `connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X1: No such file or directory`.

If I `startx icewm` on my machine, then ssh to the pi, and then `startlxde-pi`, then it works.

Is there any way to start a X server on my machine with nothing on it, just waiting for me to "fill" it up with a desktop enfironment remotely over SSH?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -X` connects the remotely started programs to the X on the SSH client side. Obviously that is possible only if there is an X to connect to.

Maybe a virtual X server is what you are looking for (on the pi or on your SSH client).

Comment: So how do I open an X server with nothing in it?

Comment: @LhakrymaDL I can't tell you that, I never used it. That would be a different question. The first thing Google finds is `Xvfb`.